# How to dynamically turn off and on email sending?

Tags: python, django, django-email

I have a model Reservation which sends email to user when it's created.

For testing purposes, I want to populate database with hundreds of `Reservations` from time to time.

It can produce thousands of emails so I would like to turn off email sending, or dynamically change email backend if possible.

I can't do bulk create because I need to perform `save` method for every `Reservation` model.

The only thing which comes to my mind is to temporarily change `settings.py` but maybe there is a better way to do that (I may forgot to change settings).

```
def create_random_reservations(count=10, user='futilestudio'):
    users = User.objects.all()
    airports = Location.objects.filter(is_airport=True)
    cities = Location.objects.filter(is_airport=False)

    for n in range(count / 2):
        dt = datetime(year=2017, month=9, day=random.choice(range(15, 20)), hour=random.choice(range(12, 22)),
                      minute=random.choice(range(60)))
        r = Reservation.objects.create(customer_first_name=get_random_string(10),
                                       customer_last_name=get_random_string(10), flight_number=get_random_string(5),
                                       destination_from=random.choice(airports), destination_to=random.choice(cities),
                                       date_arrival=dt.date(), time_arrival=dt.time(), customer=random.choice(users))
        r.confirm(save=True)
```

Comment: Why don't you add a parameter, send_mail=True in confirm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have at least two distinct settings files - one for production and one for dev. Just set your dev settings EMAIL_BACKEND to [something that does not effectively send mails](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/email/#console-backend) for your dev environment.